# Why is parameter passed to scriptblock being converted to a string?

Tags: powershell

I want to pass the `$writer` variable to the `ScriptBlock` as is, so I can write to the stream from within the ScriptBlock. But, I get:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'sw'. Cannot convert value "[System.IO.StreamWriter]System.IO.StreamWriter" to type "System.IO.StreamWriter". Error: "Access to the path 
'C:\windows\system32\[System.IO.StreamWriter]System.IO.StreamWriter' is denied."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

This seems to suggest `$writer` is being converted to a string. I've tried so many different combinations of casting, but nothing works I can find.

My code:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText('C:\users\<removed>\downloads\queryfile-example-current\test.tsv')
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter 'C:\users\<removed>\downloads\queryfile-example-current\test3.tsv'
for(;;) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    if ($null -eq $line) {
        break
    }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param($record, $sw)
        $data = $record.Split("`t")

        #write-host "$($data[0] + ";" + $data[1])"
        Resolve-DnsName -Name $data[0] -Type $data[1] -DnsOnly
        $sw.WriteLine("{0}`t{1}", $data[0], $data[1])
    } -ArgumentList $line, [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer | Out-Null

    Get-Job -State Completed | Receive-Job # -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Get-Job -State Completed -HasMoreData $false | Remove-Job
}
$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()

While (Get-Job) {
    foreach ($job in get-job | where-object { $_.State -eq "Completed" -or $_.State -eq "Failed"})
    {
        if ($job.HasMoreData) {
            Receive-Job $job
        }
        elseif ($job.State -eq "Failed") {
            Receive-Job $job
        }
        else {
            Remove-Job $job
        }
    }
    sleep -seconds 1
}
```

Comment: What you're looking to do is not thread safe.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm assuming that is because there would be no determinate order of the written lines. But, I don't care. As long as each line is written in whole. The other possibility is that the lines would be intermingled - is that what would happen?

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I meant that even if what you want to do worked, if 2 or more threads tries to write at the same time you will lose information. In this case this wont even begin to work because `Start-Job` doesnt use threads, it uses processes, and you can't just pass a `StreamWriter` reference between processes.

Comment: Is it important that the `WriteLine()` call occurs inside the background job? Are you trying to make some sort of progress tracker? What is it that you're trying to achieve by "reusing" the same writer? Performance? Thread safety?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen To not distract from the actual question I will avoid going in to details here about that. I understand the non-thread safe routine, and I have instead passed the output back to the main process and moved writeline there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the valid points raised by @SantiagoSquarzon about thread-safety, the literal answer to your question as it's currently written is that `[System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer` isn't being *converted* to a string - it's being *parsed* as one.

Here's a slightly modified example:

```
$sb = {
    Start-Job `
        -ScriptBlock { param($sw) } `
        -ArgumentList [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer `
    | Out-Null
}

# show the abstract syntax tree element parsed from the code
$sb.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[4]

#Value              : [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer
#StringConstantType : BareWord
#                     ^^^^^^^^ - basically an unquoted string
#NestedExpressions  : {$writer}
#StaticType         : System.String
#Extent             : [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer
#Parent             : Start-Job `
#                             -ScriptBlock { param($sw) } `
#                             -ArgumentList #[System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer
```

If you want it to be parsed and evaluated as a PowerShell expression you can use the [Grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#grouping-operator--) to force PowerShell to treat it as code rather than a string:

```
$sb = {
    Start-Job `
        -ScriptBlock { param($sw) } `
        -ArgumentList ([System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer) `
    | Out-Null
}
#                     ^ ----  note the brackets  ---- ^

# show the abstract syntax tree element parsed from the code
$sb.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[4]

#Pipeline                        StaticType    Extent                            Parent
#--------                        ----------    ------                            ------
#[System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer System.Object ([System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer) Start-Job `…
```

And if you want an even simpler example, try this:

```
PS> write-host 2+2
# 2+2

PS> write-host (2+2)
# 4
```

In the first command, `2+2` is being treated as a string and gets written to the console verbatim, but when we wrap it with the grouping operator it gets treated as an expression and evaluated before being passed to `write-host`. This is basically what's happening with your `[System.IO.StreamWriter]$writer` - there's just a bit more going on around it so it's harder to see...

This might not help you with your actual goal, but it hopefully answers your question about what's going on...

---

**Update** - here's some further reading suggested by @MatthiasRJessen that gives a lot more insight if you want the definitive reference:

- [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Argument mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#argument-mode)

Specifically, quoted from the "Argument mode" section:

> When parsing, PowerShell first looks to interpret input as an expression. But when a command invocation is encountered, parsing continues in argument mode.
>
> ...
>
> All input is treated as an expandable string unless it uses one of the following syntaxes:
>
> ...
>
> - `()`, `$()`, and `@()` at the start of a token create a new parsing context that can contain expressions or nested commands.

Comment: Nice. I suggest linking to [`about_Parsing` § Argument Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#argument-mode)